# VPAID ad unit in javascript

Tags: jwplayer, flowplayer, vast

Does anyone have an example of a VPAID ad unit built in javascript?

Comment: Not yet. I have not seen any examples of these tags yet, or any players that support these yet.

Comment: Would love to know if you found any examples in the end - Struggling to find any decent examples of javascript VPAID online, the IAB page seems to be the only help, though it appears I am still missing something, as my script is not quite working on test pages... (IAB page: http://www.iab.net/media/file/VPAID_2.0_Final_04-10-2012.pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of ad using VPAID JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854732/example-of-ad-using-vpaid-javascript-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really like to necropost but still this question in top by VPAID search query here is some JS examples:

Here is VAST tags examples - http://ryanthompson591.github.io/vpaidExamples/

And source of some JS VPAID can be found [here](https://github.com/ryanthompson591/vpaidExamples/)