# Example of ad using VPAID JavaScript API

Tags: vast

I'm struggling to find an example of an HTML5 VAST/VPAID ad. IAB's [VPAID spec](http://www.iab.net/media/file/VPAID_2.0_Final_04-10-2012.pdf) doesn't include a good example on how to use the JavaScript VPAID APIs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Answering my own question since I think this will be useful for others.

You can find a bunch of JS VPAID ad examples here: https://github.com/ryanthompson591/vpaidExamples/

If you need the VAST tags, you can get them from here:
http://ryanthompson591.github.io/vpaidExamples/

Comment: Thanks! Can you also recommend some JS VPAID players that are good for development/testing?

Comment: You can use [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com) with any of these two plugins to play VAST ads: https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima or http://theonion.github.io/videojs-vast-plugin/

Comment: I should add: I've used the IMA SDK to play VPAID ads, but I haven't used TheOnion's, although it seems like it [supports JS VPAID](https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin/pull/50)

Comment: more vasts examples here http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/index_4.html

Comment: The question is how do you create vpaid tag url?

Comment: You can host the XML and JS files and point your ad server to the XML URL. The VAST/VPAID ad tag will be this URL.